# react router takes some time to redirect/render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why?

Without router it renders instantly, but with router it takes 5 seconds to render login component at page refresh.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={()=>Loading()} persistor={persistor}>
    <Router history={hist}>


        <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/rtl" render={props => <RTLLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/apps" render={props => <AppsLayout {...props} />} />

        <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />
```

Comment: What is the code of your login component ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
        <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/rtl" render={props => <RTLLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/apps" render={props => <AppsLayout {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
```

If you are trying to render the login component on every visit to your app i would suggest you to use a different approach.
I would suggest that you define a state variable `isLoggedIn: false` in your `app.js(or whatever your landing page is)`, then you can test its value inside render.

```
if(!this.state.isLoggedIn) {
     this.props.history.push('/login');
   } else {
    //whatever you want
   }
```

or

```
if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to='/login'/>
   } else {
    return <HomePage/>
   }
```

it's your wish how you want to achieve what you are seeking.

Comment: you can send the value i.e `isLoggedIn` from the `app.js` to the `Login` component using props and then you can update the value from child into parent by using callback function. so you will not be needing redirect at all and this would be the best way.